# Using Visual Studio for VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for an opportunity to use Visual Studio for VBA. Specially for Excel Makros. Reason is, to use all the supporting Features of Visual Studio e.g. TFS Connection. Is that possible?

Comment: This is an open ended question. SO doesn't really lend itself to those types of questions. You might want to ask this on quora instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create [VSTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) projects in Visual Studio instead